# PyCharm Gauss – Unresolved reference

Tags: python-3.x

I have a sample python program provided below:

```
import pandas as pd
from Gauss import Gauss

print("\t\tVar 25\n")
data = pd.read_excel('Trilinear_Interpolation.xlsx')

power_X = len(data.X.unique()) - 1
power_Y = len(data.Y.unique()) - 1
power_Z = len(data.Z.unique()) - 1

A = []
for j in range((power_X+1) * (power_Y+1) * (power_Z+1)):
    s = []
    for i in range(power_X, -1, -1):
        for k in range(power_Y, -1, -1):
            for l in range(power_Z, -1, -1):
                s.append((data['X'][j]**i)*(data['Y'][j]**k)*(data['Z'][j]**l))
    A.append(s)

b = []
for j in range((power_X+1) * (power_Y+1) * (power_Z+1)):
    b.append(data['F'][j])

c = Gauss(A, b)

polynom_string = 'P(x,y,z) = '
j = 0
for i in range(power_X, -1, -1):
    for k in range(power_Y, -1, -1):
        for l in range(power_Z, -1, -1):
            polynom_string = polynom_string + str(c[j]) + '*x^' + str(i) + '*y^' + str(k) + '*z^' + str(l) + '+'
            j = j + 1
polynom_string = polynom_string[:-9].replace('+-', '-').replace('x^1', 'x').replace('y^1', 'y').replace('z^1', 'z')
polynom_string = polynom_string.replace('*x^0', '').replace('*y^0', '').replace('*z^0', '')

print('Інтерполяційний поліном')
print(polynom_string)
```

The `import Gauss` statement is underlined with red:

[image]

When I try to run the program, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/Programming/PyCharm Workspace/pythonProject/lab5.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Gauss import Gauss
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gauss'
```

What can it be?
I work in PyCharm, but other IDEs like VS Code throw the same kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package Gauss, or are you sure the spelling is correct? Please check these things, and the code may work. Also, Pycharm works on a separate python environment, due to which packages installed globally may not be available inside the Pycharm python environment, hence, you could try to use the terminal in the Pycharm environment to reinstall the library and reinstall the package. Then, the library may not work. You could also check the folders in Pycharm and check the python instance folder to check what libraries have been installed in the instance to find out if your library has been installed, and it might work...